# Make Sort ignore field in model

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've encountered a problem:

I'm accepting the sortBy string in the controller and creating Sort object with Sort.by(sortBy).
The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to block fields from being sorted.

For example, I have:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String encryptedPassword;
```

I would like to block being able to sort by a password.

My controller method:

```
@GetMapping(produces = { MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public PagedModel<EntityModel<UserDetailsResponse>> getUsers(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                                                             @RequestParam Integer size,
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "createDate") String sortBy,
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) String order) {
    Sort.Direction sortDirection = Sort.Direction.fromOptionalString(order)
            .orElse(Sort.Direction.DESC);

    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortDirection, sortBy));

    Page<UserDTO> users = userService.getUsers(pageRequest);

    Page<UserDetailsResponse> userDetailsResponses = users.stream()
            .map((userDTO) -> modelMapper.map(userDTO, UserDetailsResponse.class))
            .map(this::addRelations)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), PageImpl::new));

    return pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(userDetailsResponses);
}
```

Of course, I could create a blacklist with field names, but I'm looking for a non-hardcoding way.

Is there some annotation or other way I could use to achieve that?

Comment: Could you change the name of `encryptedPassword` to something like `_encryptedPassword` (now starts with an underscore) and then forbid sorting on anything that starts with an underscore? That would still be a sort of a blacklist but it would at least be implicit. On the other hand, I think that an explicit blacklist gives the most readable and least error prone code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't appear to be any annotation for that, I wrote my own.
If someone stumbles upon this problem here's the code:

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SortBlacklisted {
}
```

SortBlackListUtil:

```
@Component
public class SortBlackListUtil {

    /**
     * Looks for fields annotated with @SortBlacklisted in the specified class
     * and creates blacklist form their names.
     *
     * @param classToLookIn Class to search in for @SortBlacklisted annotation.
     * @param <T> Class object type.
     * @return List of blacklisted fields names for the specified class.
     */
    public <T> ArrayList<String> getBlackListedFields(Class<T> classToLookIn) {
        ArrayList<String> blackListedFieldsNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Field field : classToLookIn.getDeclaredFields()) {
            SortBlacklisted sortBlacklisted = field.getAnnotation(SortBlacklisted.class);

            if (sortBlacklisted != null) blackListedFieldsNames.add(field.getName());
        }

        return blackListedFieldsNames;
    }
}
```

Now simply place that an annotation on the desired field

```
@SortBlacklisted
private String encryptedPassword;
```

Use that method to get a list of blacklisted fields names:

```
sortBlackListUtil.getBlackListedFields(MyClass.class)
```